# STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED on a call to NtQueryMutant

Tags: c++, winapi, ntdll, undocumented-behavior

**Disclaimer:**

The only reason for the question and the code below to exist is an external component used in my application, which cannot be replaced, at least in the near future. This component's logic intercepts WinAPI calls from the application and performs various tasks based on these calls.

One of the things the component does, it creates mutex for each thread initialized inside the application. However, it doesn't close the mutexes, which results in handles leak.

Therefore, in order to prevent the leak and because I don't have access to the component's source code, I have to invent ugly workarounds and use esoteric API's.

**End of disclaimer**

I am trying to check state of mutexes in my application. In order to do this without changing the state of each of the objects I check, I have to use the `NtQueryMutant` method from *ntdll.dll*.

Based on examples [here](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FMutant%2FNtQueryMutant.html) and [here](http://forum.sysinternals.com/check-mutant-state-without-altering-its-state_topic27466.html) I wrote the following code to achieve this:

```
enum MUTANT_INFORMATION_CLASS
{
    MutantBasicInformation
};

struct MUTANT_BASIC_INFORMATION {
    LONG CurrentCount;
    BOOLEAN OwnedByCaller;
    BOOLEAN AbandonedState;
};

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI*QueryMutexHandler)(HANDLE, MUTANT_INFORMATION_CLASS, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);

//somewhere in the code:
QueryMutexHandler queryMutex = reinterpret_cast<QueryMutexHandler>(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryMutant"));
MUTANT_BASIC_INFORMATION mutantInfo;
NTSTATUS status = queryMutex(objectHandleCopy, MutantBasicInformation, &mutantInfo, sizeof(MUTANT_BASIC_INFORMATION), nullptr);
if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
     //never arriving here
}
```

The `status` I receive here is always *-1073741790 (0xFFFF FFFF C000 0022)* which is, except being negative number, looks exactly like [STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx).

That is very strange, because previously in code I use both `NtQuerySystemInformation` and `NtQueryObject` without any problem.

**Additional details:** my OS is Windows 7 SP1, the mutexes I try to query belong to the process I am performing the query from.

Comment: Why do you need to check the state of a mutex? Check-before-use is a great way to introduce very common race condition bugs.

Comment: @andlabs This is a dirty workaround-hack to prevent handle leaks in external component used by the application.

Comment: you not show how you open mutant. for query you need have MUTANT_QUERY_STATE access in handle. faster of all you have no this access. and NtQueryObject here unrelated because it not require any access rights on handle.  NtQuerySystemInformation - at all unrelated

Comment: I think RbMm is right that this is most likely an access-rights issue.  If that hint doesn't resolve your problem, post the code.  Note also that NTSTATUS is an unsigned 32-bit type (even on 64-bit systems) so that really is STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, you're just improperly sign-extending it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston the value I show here is what I see in the debugger watch. So yes, it is STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, just shown improperly.

Comment: @RbMm I don't open the mutex, external dll I reference does. I am using the NtQuerySystemInformation in order to get the list of all the handles related to my process. Then, I can take only those which have the "mutant" type name, by using the NtQueryObject. In order to query the mutex, I call NtDuplicateObject on the handle returned from NtQuerySystemInformation with DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS option. I guess, the later could be a problem?

Comment: `DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS` gives you a handle with the same level of access as the original. But you did nothing to ensure that the original handle had `MUTANT_QUERY_STATE` access. If you want `MUTANT_QUERY_STATE`, you need to ask for it.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes, I understand this. The question is what's the minimum set of DesiredAccess flags to specify so I can query the mutex, is the MUTANT_QUERY_STATE by itself enough?

Comment: I don't know, but that's what RbMm claims. You made no attempt to acquire any particular access, so the fact that you get access denied is not surprising.

Comment: @RaymondChen I would expect that mutex is originally created with the flags allowing to query its state.

Comment: yes, `MUTANT_QUERY_STATE` is enough for query. and you not need duplicate handle always. look for `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX.GrantedAccess` value for mutex handle - if it containing `MUTANT_QUERY_STATE` use handle as is, if no - call `ZwDuplicateObject(NtCurrentProcess(), hMutant, NtCurrentProcess(),&hMutant2, 
   MUTANT_QUERY_STATE, 0, 0)`

Comment: @RbMm Could you post you comment as an answer please, so I could mark it in case of success?

Comment: Any chance that the third-party component is also intercepting the call to NtQueryMutant?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - don`t think that somebody will intercepting NtQueryMutant - this is very rare called, even hard imaging case - for what this api need

Comment: in all case hook easy visible under debugger. and STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED say about that handle value is correct (if not we got STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE) and object is really mutant (if not we got STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH) - access mask is checked latest. but may be galenys some confuse - this is most possible case

Answer (score 2):

for effective test Mutant you need it handle and it access mask. you can got it from `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX` structure. if we already have `MUTANT_QUERY_STATE` - can direct query, if no - need reopen handle with `MUTANT_QUERY_STATE`

```
NTSTATUS QueryMutant(HANDLE hMutant, ULONG GrantedAccess, MUTANT_BASIC_INFORMATION* pmbi)
{
    if (GrantedAccess & MUTANT_QUERY_STATE)
    {
        return ZwQueryMutant(hMutant, MutantBasicInformation, pmbi, sizeof(MUTANT_BASIC_INFORMATION), 0);
    }

    NTSTATUS status = ZwDuplicateObject(NtCurrentProcess(), hMutant, NtCurrentProcess(),&hMutant, 
        MUTANT_QUERY_STATE, 0, 0);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        status = ZwQueryMutant(hMutant, MutantBasicInformation, pmbi, sizeof(MUTANT_BASIC_INFORMATION), 0);
        ZwClose(hMutant);
    }

    return status;
}
```

and you not need all time use NtQueryObject for determinate type of handle. you can use `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX.ObjectTypeIndex` . for get [OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntobapi_8h_source.html#l00068) by this index. for this you need only once call `ZwQueryObject(0, ObjectAllTypeInformation, )` at start, but exist problem how convert `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX.ObjectTypeIndex` to array index (zero bassed). begin from win8.1 'OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION.TypeIndex' is valid and match to `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX.ObjectTypeIndex`, but for early version - you need once get `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX.ObjectTypeIndex` for some known object type and calc delta

```
static volatile UCHAR guz;

NTSTATUS getProcessIndex(USHORT& ObjectTypeIndex)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    NTSTATUS status = ZwDuplicateObject(NtCurrentProcess(), NtCurrentProcess(), NtCurrentProcess(), &hProcess, 0, 0, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
        DWORD cb = 0, rcb = 0x10000;

        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX pshti;
        };

        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb) cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);

            if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemExtendedHandleInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
            {
                if (ULONG NumberOfHandles = (ULONG)pshti->NumberOfHandles)
                {
                    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX Handles = pshti->Handles;

                    ULONG_PTR UniqueProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
                    do 
                    {
                        if (Handles->UniqueProcessId == UniqueProcessId && (HANDLE)Handles->HandleValue == hProcess)
                        {
                            ObjectTypeIndex = Handles->ObjectTypeIndex;
                            goto __break;
                        }

                    } while (Handles++, --NumberOfHandles);
                }
            }

        } while (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH == status);

__break:
        ZwClose(hProcess);
    }

    return status;
}

class ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION
{
    OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* _TypeInformation;
    DWORD _NumberOfTypes, _TypeIndexDelta;

public:

    operator DWORD()
    {
        return _NumberOfTypes;
    }

    operator OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION*()
    {
        return _TypeInformation;
    }

    DWORD operator[](OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* TypeInformation)
    {
        return (DWORD)(TypeInformation - _TypeInformation) + _TypeIndexDelta;
    }

    OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* operator[](DWORD Index)
    {
        return Index < _NumberOfTypes ? _TypeInformation + Index : 0;
    }

    ULONG TypeIndexToIndex(DWORD ObjectTypeIndex)
    {
        return ObjectTypeIndex -= _TypeIndexDelta;
    }

    OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* operator[](PCUNICODE_STRING TypeName);

    ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION();

    ~ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION();
};

ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION g_AOTI;

OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION::operator[](PCUNICODE_STRING TypeName)
{
    if (DWORD NumberOfTypes = _NumberOfTypes)
    {
        OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* TypeInformation = _TypeInformation;

        do 
        {
            if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(TypeName, &TypeInformation->TypeName, TRUE))
            {
                return TypeInformation;
            }
        } while (TypeInformation++, -- NumberOfTypes);
    }

    return 0;
}

ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION::ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION()
{
    _TypeInformation = 0, _NumberOfTypes = 0;

    USHORT ProcessTypeIndex;
    if (0 > getProcessIndex(ProcessTypeIndex))
    {
        return ;
    }

    NTSTATUS status;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        OBJECT_TYPES_INFORMATION* poati;
    };

    DWORD cb = 0, rcb = 0x2000;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryObject(0, ObjectAllTypeInformation, poati, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            if (DWORD NumberOfTypes = poati->NumberOfTypes)
            {
                if (OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* TypeInformation = (OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION*)LocalAlloc(0, rcb))
                {
                    _NumberOfTypes = NumberOfTypes;
                    _TypeInformation = TypeInformation;

                    ULONG Index = 0;

                    union {
                        ULONG_PTR uptr;
                        OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* pti;
                    };

                    union {
                        PWSTR buf;
                        PBYTE pb;
                        PVOID pv;
                    };

                    pti = poati->TypeInformation;
                    pv = TypeInformation + NumberOfTypes;

                    do 
                    {
                        STATIC_UNICODE_STRING_(Process);

                        if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(&Process, &pti->TypeName, TRUE))
                        {
                            _TypeIndexDelta = ProcessTypeIndex - Index;
                        }

                        ULONG Length = pti->TypeName.Length, MaximumLength = pti->TypeName.MaximumLength;
                        memcpy(buf, pti->TypeName.Buffer, Length);

                        *TypeInformation = *pti;
                        TypeInformation++->TypeName.Buffer = buf;
                        pb += Length;
                        uptr += (sizeof(OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION) + MaximumLength + sizeof(PVOID)-1) & ~ (sizeof(PVOID)-1);
                    } while (Index++, --NumberOfTypes);
                }
            }
        } 
    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);
}

ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION::~ZOBJECT_ALL_TYPES_INFORMATION()
{
    if (_TypeInformation)
    {
        LocalFree(_TypeInformation);
    }
}
```

and finally use next code, without NtQueryObject:

```
void TestMutant()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    DWORD cb = 0, rcb = 0x10000;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX pshti;
    };

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb) cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemExtendedHandleInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            if (ULONG NumberOfHandles = (ULONG)pshti->NumberOfHandles)
            {
                PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX Handles = pshti->Handles;

                ULONG_PTR UniqueProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
                do 
                {
                    if (Handles->UniqueProcessId == UniqueProcessId)
                    {
                        if (OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* poti = g_AOTI[g_AOTI.TypeIndexToIndex(Handles->ObjectTypeIndex)])
                        {
                            STATIC_UNICODE_STRING_(Mutant);

                            if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(&Mutant, &poti->TypeName, TRUE))
                            {
                                MUTANT_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
                                QueryMutant((HANDLE)Handles->HandleValue, Handles->GrantedAccess, &mbi);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } while (Handles++, --NumberOfHandles);
            }
        }

    } while (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH == status);
}
```

can test with

```
    void Az()
{
    HANDLE hMutant;
    if (0 <= ZwCreateMutant(&hMutant, SYNCHRONIZE, 0, TRUE))
    {
        TestMutant();
        ZwClose(hMutant);
    }
}
```

Comment: I receive a **0x1F0001** for the GrantedAccess field, but still, the `NtQueryMutant` fails with the same status code.

Comment: @galenus - this is strange, because #define MUTANT_QUERY_STATE 0x0001 is enough. i test by self and look for example https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ex/mutant.c

Comment: @galenus need more look in live system why this happens. only based on your info hard say

Comment: I'll try to bake some example solution and put on github so you could see it by yourself, I will let you know here if I get to this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @galenus - can for test create mutant by self with and without MUTANT_QUERY_STATE and test this with my  `QueryMutant` as start point

Comment: @galenus - i paste full code, can only advice you first in separate program by self create mutant(with different access) ant test got it state